# Is there a way to change the cover photo in Gmail app's menu?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

Gmail/G+ allows you to change the cover photo along with the profile photo. **I already changed both**. The profile photo will also be used in the Gmail app on most (every?) Android. But what about the cover photo? I don't want the Google default cover photo on my Gmail app.

[image: cover photo wasn't not reflected]

I'm on a Samsung using Android 5.0. Gmail app is currently on 5.6.103338659.release.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: The background image of the Gmail android app comes from the Google+ profile background. By the other hand this question belongs is off-topic here. See [help/on-topic] for further details.

Comment: My G+ background is another image. It's not working as you suggest.

Comment: Check the sync settings.

Comment: Sync is on, naturally. How else could my profile pic change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, as a matter of fact, the image suddenly appeared. I did not do anything special that I hadn't tried before: Switching on and off the phone, reconnecting gmail, disabling and enabling the respective settings.

So it's obviously just a matter of time until all the picture changes take effect in the app.